# Event Conflict with MSQL & PHP event calendar

Tags: php, mysql, database, events, calendar

So I am working on a client website and it includes an event calendar as its main focus. The calendar functions: you can insert events with a date,start_time,end_time. and then its displayed on the calendar and you get the picture. The problem I am having is conflicts between current events and ones people are trying to book as new events. I know logically I will need to check if its:

1. between the event
2. during the event but starting before it
3. during the event but starting during it and ending afterwards.

The sql query I made up to start is this(it doesnt work):

```
$check_date_time = "SELECT `event_date`, `start_time`, `end_time` FROM `calendar_events` WHERE
 '.$_POST['event_date'].' = event_date AND
'.$_POST['start_time'].' BETWEEN `start_time` AND `end_time` 
AND '.$_POST['start_time'].' < `start_time` AND '.$_POST['end_time'].' < `end_time` 
|| '.$_POST['start_time'].' > `start_time` AND '.$_POST['end_time'].' < `end_time`';
$result = mysql_query($check_date_time, $mysql)
            or die(mysql_error());
```

Any help would be appreciated, I dont know if I am writing the query wrong or if the database is setup wrong.

Thanks, Andrew

Comment: for the current query I get this error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':1:00 BETWEEN start_time AND end_time AND 1:1:00 < start_time AND 1:1:00 < end_' at line 3

Comment: What is the format of `$_POST` variables you're inserting into the query? And also, what is the data type of the data columns you are trying to make a comparison to? From your error message, it appears that it is failing due to either a mismatch of types or an improper time format.

Comment: please tell us the `datatype` of your table attributes

Comment: event_date = date

start_time = time

end_time = time

Comment: I build the $_POST vars as such:

event time is date('Y-m-d')

start and end time is date('H:i:s')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're storing the dates and times in a text/varchar field and attempting to use the BETWEEN operator which only works on date/numerical fields.

Run this query: SHOW CREATE TABLE `calendar_events`;

And post back the results for us so we can see your table structure.

Also I should point out that putting $_POST data **directly** into a SQL query is a very very veeeeerrrrry bad idea under any circumstance. That's how you expose yourself to SQL injection attacks and get your entire database compromised.

You should use a helper class or at least calling mysql_escape_string or using the escape method on mysqli around each data element. Also, make sure you wrap your parameters in the query in single quotes. You should also wrap your table/column names in backticks (`). Even though they are technically optional, it does help when reading queries and it avoids the errors caused by data/fieldname collision.

For example if I posted "event_date" as the data for $_POST['event_date'] MySQL would get confused since it would interpret that part of the query as `event_date` = `event_date` which of course will **always** be true.

With single quotes and backticks properly used: 'event_date' = `event_date` Now MySQL knows that the first occurrence is telling it to look for cases where the value of event_date is present in the event_date column of the table.

At any rate, post back the table structure, put your single/backtick quotes in place, and I think it'll be much easier for us to help you.

Comment: Okay thanks Brian for the great response. This being only the second project I have had that included sql, im fairly new to it. I can post the table structure if you need it but I can tell you without running that command that the event_date is a 'date' and the start & end times are 'time' . But the single/backtick quotes is a good tip( i always saw them in phpMyAdmin but never knew why they had them in the query section. I wont be able to post anymore information till later tonight as the files are at home and I am at work right now. Thanks again.

Comment: 1 id int(11)

2 event_title varchar(200) utf8_general_ci 

3 event_description varchar(255) utf8_general_ci 

4 member_id varchar(255) utf8_general_ci 

5 event_date date

6 start_time time

7 end_time time

8 num_people varchar(255) utf8_general_ci 

9 catering tinyint(1)

10 approved tinyint(4)

11 event_admin tinyint(4)

12 first_name varchar(255) utf8_general_ci 

13 last_name varchar(255) utf8_general_ci 

14 user_email varchar(255) utf8_general_ci 

15 private_public varchar(10) utf8_general_ci

Comment: I simply only have to check if there is at least one conflict and not really where the conflict exists in the calendar. So this query 

`$check_date_time = "SELECT * FROM `calendar_events` WHERE '".$_POST['event_date']."' = `event_date` AND CAST('".$_POST['start_time']."' AS time) BETWEEN `start_time` AND `end_time`
        OR '".$_POST['event_date']."' = `event_date` AND (NOT CAST('".$_POST['end_time']."' AS time) BETWEEN `end_time` AND `start_time` AND `start_time` > `end_time`)";
$result = mysql_query($check_date_time, $mysql)
   or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: and then check if $result strlen comes out more then zero say there is a time conflict. But with this It always finds a conflict because I dont think it is checking "on a certain is there a conflict with time" its just checking if any start time and end time meet this requirement. Would I have to make them datetime columns again? @Brian

Comment: Actually this is just a thought, but since you're new to developing, you might consider converting your date/time columns into unsigned INT(11) fields and storing Unix Timestamps instead. A Unix Timestamp is basically the number of seconds that have passed since the Unix Epooch. There is a handy MySQL function FROM_UNIXTIME() that can convert a unix timestamp to a MySQL formatted timestamp like what you're using now. However, you don't need to convert it for comparisons like the one you're using, and you also don't need to convert it in PHP when you load data from the DB.

Comment: For that reason, many developers tend to use unix timestamps to store date/time information. They're much easier to work with and easier to run the types of comparisons you typically run on date/time information. Since everything is boiled down to a number representing the distance of that point in time from the start of 1970 (a fixed point in time) comparisons are done exactly the way you're doing them, but working with the data is far easier since you can use php's time functions to work with the date/time information and store the result in the DB without the need to convert it.

Comment: This is what I used to get it working, thanks for your tips,help, and
insight


`$check_date_time = "SELECT * FROM `calendar_events` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `calendar_events` WHERE 
 (`event_date_start` <= '$event_date_start' AND `event_date_end` >= '$event_date_start') OR
  (`event_date_start` <= '$event_date_end' AND `event_date_end` >= '$event_date_end') OR
      (`event_date_start` >= '$event_date_start' AND `event_date_end` <= '$event_date_end'))";
$result = mysql_query($check_date_time, $mysql)
   or die(mysql_error());
   
   
 if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{}`

@Brian

Answer (score 0):

@Brian – This is what I used to get it working, thanks for your tips,help, and insight

```
$check_date_time = "SELECT * FROM calendar_events` WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM  
calendar_events WHERE (event_date_start <= '$event_date_start' AND event_date_end >=   
'$event_date_start') OR (event_date_start <= '$event_date_end' AND event_date_end >=
'$event_date_end') OR (event_date_start >= '$event_date_start' AND event_date_end <=  
'$event_date_end'))"; $result = mysql_query($check_date_time, $mysql) or 
die(mysql_error()); 
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {}
```

the event date start and end are date/time columns in my database and I check if an 'id'(a row) meets any of the conditions, if so it stops the user and displays a notice saying there is an event in that slot. But this does allow more then one event a day to occur.